# PKIX path building unable to find valid certification path to requested target at Digital Ocean

Tags: docker, openssl, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean

We have created docker container at digital ocean. our tomcat is running inside docker container and Apache web server is running at digital ocean. we configured SSL at Apache we server and keep the location details of certification into httpd-ssl file. JAVA is running inside container. After configured SSL certification at Apache web server, we are getting an exception if any remote URL hit the our application. The exception is

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

As we used to update cacerts inside java by following command
keytool -import -alias alias -keystore /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts  -file myserver.cer

Can anyone help me over this issue ?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What version of Java were you running ? I mean which exact version, like 1.8.0_241-b07

Comment: For me it was my VPN not working properly. When I used my phone as a hotspot the error disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

According to me this re the possible error, kindly have a look:

It is the error with the certificate path and also check the private key with the certificate which you got are not mismatching.
The commands that you are running to import the certificate in java keytool server alias name is not mentioned in your command so this could be the reason you are getting the error

Hope it was informative to you to solve the problem.

Regards,
Https India

Comment: Hi, we have mentioned alias name as alias and can see "alias" in cacerts too. Certificate path seems to correct for me because we can see green lock at browser against my URL (we got this green after putting my certificate).